# Como inserir espaço em string CamelCase?

Tags: javascript, array, string, vue.js, camel-case

Estou procurando uma forma de separar string de um objeto array, vindo de uma API, por exemplo: PageViews, ficar Page Views, estou utilizando VUEJS.

Comment: Nota: `PageViews` não está em camel mas sim em pascal case, para estar em camel teria de ser `pageViews`

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um exemplo para implementar no seu código:

> **var regx1 = texto.match(/[A-Z]/gm)[1]:** Nesta linha pego a segunda ocorrência de letra maiúscula `V`.

---

> **texto = texto.replace(regx1,' '+regx1):** Nesta linha troco o `V` por espaço e insiro ele novamente com todo o texto depois dele.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    stringOriginal: 'PageViews'     
  },
  methods: {
    stringSeparada() {
     var texto = this.stringOriginal;
     var regx1 = texto.match(/[A-Z]/gm)[1];
     texto = texto.replace(regx1,' '+regx1);
     return texto  
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">

  <input type="text" v-model="stringOriginal" /> <br/>
  
  <p>
    Separada: {{ stringSeparada() }}
  </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a forma mais simples seria apenas usar o método [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) com uma regex que casará apenas com letras maiúsculas.

Se você ler [esta sessão](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) da documentação do `String.replace()`, verá que o segundo parâmetro pode ser uma função ou uma string. Se você utilizar uma string você pode usar alguns caracteres especiais para ganhar algumas funcionalidade a mais. Estes caracteres são:

- `$&`: Substitui pela string casada. Ex.:

  ```
  "...abc123def...".replace(/\d+/, '{{$&}}') 
  // output: "...abc{{123}}def..."
  ```
- `` $` ``: Substitui pela parte anterior à string casada

  ```
  "...abc123def...".replace(/\d+/, '{{$`}}')
  // output: "...abc{{...abc}}def..."
  ```
- `$'`: Substitui pela parte posterior à string casada

  ```
  "...abc123def...".replace(/\d+/, "{{$'}}")
  // output: "...abc{{def...}}def..."
  ```
- `$n`: Substitui pelo enésimo grupo casado na Regex

  ```
  "00011122233".replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/, "$1.$2.$3-$4")
  // output: "000.111.222-33"
  ```

Então bastaria fazer um simples replace com a regex e estaria resolvido:

```
"PageView".replace(/[A-Z]/g, " $&").trim()
```

<sup>* Usei o trim para retirar o espaço caso a primeira letra seja maiúscula. É mais simples do que criar um Regex mais complexa.</sup>

Na versão final do código eu adicionei "suporte" a acentuação. Na verdade o "suporte" é para um range [bem específico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Latin-1_Supplement) inspirado nas respostas [desta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics).

Abaixo o código final, simples e funcional:

```js
var regex = /([A-ZÀ-Þ])/gu;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { original: 'PageViewÁcentoTeste'},
  computed: {
    modificada: function() {
      return this.original.replace(regex, ' $1').trim();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="original">
  <span>"{{ modificada }}"</span>
</div>
```